# No sound on some devices

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

I have a soundboard app that uses an AVAudioSession. I attach AVAudioPlayerNodes to an AVAudioEngine to play the audio files.

Everything works great on iOS 9.2, however a lot of my reviews say the sound doesn't work. And I just tried on an iPhone 5s running iOS 8 and the sounds do not work.

I cannot figure out why this is, given the app worked fine before I updated it. And I did not make any major changes to how the sound is produced. Is there any compatibility issues with AVFoundation and iOS8 or older devices I am not aware of?

Update: When I decreased the number of nodes attached to my engine, the sound works again. It seems some devices can't handle the amount of nodes I am attaching? Wondering if a workaround for this would be to make multiple engine objects instead of just one?

Comment: Very interesting question. I did not know there were device-dependent limits on node number, though I am not entirely surprised to hear it. The way to find out whether making multiple engines is a solution would be to try it. I look forward to hearing what happens. Also I'd be interesting in knowing what the limit turned out to be, e.g. what your node graph looks like.

Comment: @matt yes, I plan to break up the nodes to different engines and see if that solves it. I will let u know in a bit here

Comment: @matt Using multiple nodes and sound still does not work. Am wondering if I should be detaching and reattaching nodes as needed?

Comment: Well, that's why I was wondering what your graph looks like: I'm asking myself what limit you could possibly have hit. If you're not actively using all those nodes at once (and I'm having trouble believing that you are), the detaching / reattaching idea seems promising. — It would also be good to file a bug report with Apple, if only to get their feedback on the matter.

Comment: @matt The original graph for a single engine had 41 nodes (before I updated my app with more sounds that brought the count up to 41, it had 15 nodes and worked fine). Now I've broken it up into 5 different nodes, with the highest node count on any single graph being 12.

Comment: That's disappointing. 41 doesn't sound excessive. But I guess it's beyond the real-time computing power of some devices!

Comment: @matt any advice on how I can use instruments to debug this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do that. I've had issues where certain sound files are playable (using AVAudioPlayer) on some devices and not others and there was absolutely to no way to detect this. Different devices just have different limitations.

Comment: @matt Right, but I believe this should work with "lazy" attaching / detaching of the nodes to the engine: that is, only creating the playerNodes and attaching them when I need to play the sound. And when the sound is complete, detaching them. I figure this wouldn't overload the CPU like it currently is

Comment: I agree, I'd hope that would solve it. What the engine must be having trouble with, you'd think, is running with a whole lot of nodes inside it simultaneously, and now you're not going to do that.